# python pip package installation JAVA_HOME error?

Tags: java, python, environment-variables, pip, boilerpipe

This issue regarding working with java and python. I would like to install, boilerpipe package using pip.

I am working it from the last two days no use.

```
pip install boilerpipe
```

getting error

```
JAVA_HOME not found.
```

JAVA JDK and JRE both are installed and environmental variables are set propperly.

user variable

```
PATH set "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"
```

and System variables

```
JAVA_HOME set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"

 path set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"
```

Whats wrong with these. please help me out.

any help will be much appreciate. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MS guy, but there might be an issue with not exporting the variables after setting them. Try setting the environment variables manually ( point and click :) ) through computer>properties..

Also, you should probably set it to reference the previously set attributes and add new, something like:

```
PATH set "$PATH;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin"
```

Sorry but, I don't know the syntax. Hope it helps a bit.

Follow this tutorial to [set the environment variables](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).